# Como apresentar dados no ArrayList em java

Tags: java, arraylist

Como eu listo as informações armazenadas em um ArrayList no java?
Segue o código para análise.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
        ArrayList<Aluno> array_aluno = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        for (int cont = 1; cont <= 3; cont++){
            aluno.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do aluno: ") );
            aluno.setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o telefone do aluno: ") );
            array_aluno.add(aluno);
        }

        for (int cont = 0; cont <= array_aluno.size() ; cont++){
            System.out.println(array_aluno.get(cont) );
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Está correto, qual a dúvida?

Comment: Olá Giuliana! O programa executa, porém os três resultados impressos são apenas o último informado. Ex: Dados do Aluno Nome = SILVA Telefone = (55)9999-9999 (imprime três vezes na tela esse mesmo resultado, ignora os anteriores)

Comment: O problema no teu código é que você criou o objeto aluno fora do primeiro for, e por isso ele sempre está sendo sobrescrito. Você precisa criá-lo dentro do for, assim serão criados 3 objetos diferentes e não apenas 1.

Comment: Era isso mesmo Giuliana, coloquei o objeto aluno para ser criado dentro do for e deu certo.
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Na classe `Aluno` você pode sobrescrever o `toString()`:

```
@Override
 public String toString() {
      return ("Nome:"+this.getNome() + " Telefone: "+ this.getTelefone());
 }
```

E usar esta estrutura no `main`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Aluno> array_aluno = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        for (int cont = 1; cont <= 3; cont++){
            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
            aluno.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o nome do aluno: ") );
            aluno.setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o telefone do aluno: ") );
            array_aluno.add(aluno);
        }

        System.out.println(array_aluno);
    }   
}
```

Após comentário de [Articundo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/articuno), movi a criação do `Aluno` para dentro do `for` (o objeto estava sempre sendo sobrescrito).

Comment: Olá rLinhares! O programa executou, porém os três resultados impressos foram apenas o último informado. Ex: 
Dados do Aluno 
Nome = SILVA 
Telefone = (55)9999-9999

Dados do Aluno 
Nome = SILVA 
Telefone = (55)9999-9999
 
Dados do Aluno 
Nome = SILVA 
Telefone = (55)9999-9999

Comment: Pelo que vi você não precisa do `for`. Vou removê-lo da resposta e você diz se resolveu.

Comment: O problema desse codigo é que ele nao vai gravar 3 alunos, e sim, sobrescrever o unico objeto aluno que está sendo criado.

Comment: @Articuno, tens razão, não tinha atentado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, coloquei o objeto aluno para ser criado dentro do for e deu certo.
Obrigado pela ajuda!